# L6234 and arduino pinout problems

Tags: arduino

**The Aim:**

I am attempting to make a gimbal controller with an Arduino Mini for two brushless motors using two L6234 chips.

**What I have done:**

I have followed the following guide and it works perfectly:
http://www.berryjam.eu/2015/04/driving-bldc-gimbals-at-super-slow-speeds-with-arduino/

Circuit:
The circuit is built as the L6234 application note suggests, exactly like the guide above suggests.

Code:
The code they have there works perfect if I use the pins as defined in the code.

**The problem:**

Due to the fact that I want to run two motors from a single micro controller I have to change the pin outs of the arduino. When I try do this the motors are no longer driven correctly.

- I have tried changing the pinout in the "void setPwmFrequency(int pin)" function too, with no success

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you
Misha

Answer (score 0):

In the very unlikely event that anyone has the same issue, here is the answer;

The arduino has been setup on pins 3,5,6,7,9,10 and 11 to operate at 32kH. Thus, to run two motors using the code, as given in the BerryJam tutorial, one simply has to ensure that the "IN" pins are one of the ones mentioned above and code accordingly. See below for pinout clarification;

```
const int iEN11 = 4;      // motor1 enable on phase 1 
const int iEN12 = 4;      // motor1 enable on phase 2 
const int iEN13 = 4;      // motor1 enable on phase 3 
const int iIN11 = 3;      // motor1 phase 1 signal         
const int iIN12 = 5;      // motor1 phase 2 signal         
const int iIN13 = 6;      // motor1 phase 3 signal         

const int iEN21 = 7;      // motor2 enable on phase 1 
const int iEN22 = 7;      // motor2 enable on phase 2 
const int iEN23 = 7;      // motor2 enable on phase 3 
const int iIN21 = 9;      // motor2 phase 1 signal         
const int iIN22 = 10;     // motor2 phase 2 signal         
const int iIN23 = 11;     // motor2 phase 3 signal
```

Hope it helps anyone.